# How can I make an interactive jQuery countdown

Tags: jquery, html, css, countdown, countdowntimer

i am trying to find a way how to create an interactive jQuery countdown:

I mean that the user must enter a value from which it value will decrease!

Do you have any suggestions?

thank you in advance!

Comment: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html or http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2013/04/jquery-countdown-scripts.html for reference, you can just take one of those scripts and alter it to your liking

Comment: an code example: http://cdn.tripwiremagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/image99.png

Comment: What format are you wanting the countdown to be in? Days? Minutes? Hours?

Comment: I want the only minutes format(for example: 15mn / 30mn / 45mn)!